# How can I reduce the value of a column in my table but not allow it to go below zero?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have this SQL that reduces a score by 1

```
db2.Execute("UPDATE Score " +

"SET EnglishCorrect = CASE WHEN EnglishCorrect > 0 THEN (EnglishCorrect -1) ELSE 0 END, " +
"KanaCorrect = CASE WHEN KanaCorrect > 0 THEN (KanaCorrect -1) ELSE 0 END,  " +
"RomajiCorrect = CASE WHEN RomajiCorrect > 0 THEN (RomajiCorrect -1) ELSE 0 END, " +
"KanjiCorrect = CASE WHEN KanjiCorrect > 0 THEN (KanjiCorrect -1) ELSE 0 END");
```

I would now like to change this so that the score is reduce by a variable number. The number will be stored in a C# integer called pts.

So I am will change the `-1` into `"- " + pts + ")"`

But I have a problem as the values of EnglishCorrect, KanaCorrect, RomajiCorrect and KanjiCorrect cannot be less than zero.

Can someone suggest how I can make it so that points are reduced to zero and nothing less.

So for example if EnglishCorrect is 5 and pts is 6 then I want EnglishCorrect to change to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   "SET EnglishCorrect = CASE WHEN (EnglishCorrect -pts)>= 0 THEN (EnglishCorrect -pts) ELSE 0 END, " +
    "KanaCorrect = CASE WHEN KanaCorrect -pts >= 0 THEN (KanaCorrect -pts) ELSE 0 END,  " +
    "RomajiCorrect = CASE WHEN RomajiCorrect-pts >= 0 THEN (RomajiCorrect -pts) ELSE 0 END, " +
    "KanjiCorrect = CASE WHEN KanjiCorrect-pts >= 0 THEN (KanjiCorrect -pts) ELSE 0 END");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and update the answer as correct if it works okay.